# I'm trying to plot surfaces in Mathematica withContourPlot3D I'm getting inconsistent results; proably syntax

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I frequently can't get it to plot anything and the output is the same as the input.
After messing with it sometimes I'm able to get it to plot but I have no clue what I'm changing. I'm trying to plot these functions

ContourPlot3D[z == cos[x], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2}]

ContourPlot3D[x == z^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]

ContourPlot3D[ z == tan[x^3 + z^2 - 3 x], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]

I input ContourPlot3D[z == cos[x], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2}] and half the time it plots. the other half it just repeats my input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematica is FaNaTiC about CoRRecT CaPItalIzaTION.  Try

Cos instead of cos

```
ContourPlot3D[z ==Cos[x], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

This should be ok

```
ContourPlot3D[x == z^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

Even Tan fails with a memory limit, I don't know what to do with this one.

```
ContourPlot3D[ z == Tan[x^3 + z^2 - 3 x], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

Try Cos instead of cos.

```
ContourPlot3D[z ==Cos[x], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

Does everything work with these changes?